# Positioning a div on 2 other divs

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position, responsive

Currently I'm building a website, and I want a small contact form to overlap a backgroud image and a part of the div above and beneath...

[image: Like this]

I've read about positioning it as absolute and setting your positions for top and right, in my dreamweaver it looks like what I want, but when I open it in my browser (in dreamweaver it's a smaller screen) the container is placed way too far down on the page. has this something to do with screen sizes and responsive design? ps: I'm totally new so my code can be messy.

the html:

```
<div id="contact">
    <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

the css:

```
#container {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 700px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 70px 5px #000000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    top: 720%;
}
```

Comment: where do you want to show the div?

Comment: Did you see the picture? it shows how I want it to be looking...

Comment: what does `top: 720%;` do?

Comment: well.... when i set position absolute the div just positions itself at the top of my website... if i set top 720% it goes down.

Comment: it looks like typo question. there should be smth like `top: 20%;`

Comment: that moves it all the way to the top of my website

Comment: define `#contact {position: relative}`, then `container` will be positioned relatively to `contact`

Comment: @Banzay that comes close to it I updated the image link, so you can see how I want it to look.

Comment: rather show how it looks actually

Comment: @Banzay http://i.imgur.com/Z6Qt1ok.png

Answer (score 0):

```
#container {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 700px;
    height: 500px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index:99999;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 70px 5px #000000;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it moves it all the way to the left and it's not really higher than the background image, so it doesn't overlap the div above and under

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="contact">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
<div>

<style type="text/css">
    .contact{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: #EEE;
    }

    .container {
    height: 200px;
    width: 350px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #e3e312;
    box-shadow: 3px 6px 26px #3A1314;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 15%;
    z-index: 999999;
}
</style>
```

Comment: That prevents it from moving itself to the left, but it's still within the background picture and not over top the section above. can you see my link now maybe that makes it more clear: https://i.imgur.com/M0oWaJh.png

Comment: Can you please view my picture? I think we're on the right track i.imgur.com/M0oWaJh.png

Comment: @LaurensvanVliet it will overlap the content of `contact div`. because i have given the z-index . Try set to set a background image for `div#contact`